# Attach object's properties or an array to a node's properties

Tags: javascript, element, nodelist, dynamic-forms

I am creating a dynamic form with many different divs inside. Each div has its own unique input combination. I have read that appendChild is faster than changing the innerHTML so my solution is to build number of arrays. Each array is a div in the form and in each array there are several objects defined. Each object is an input.

e.g:

```
        var div = [
            label = {
                tag: "label",
                text: "Enter password",
                for: "pass"
            },
                input = {
                tag: "input",
                type: "password",
                name: "pass"
            }
        ];
```

At first, I used a foreach statement to attach the object's property onto a new element using 
setAttribute like so: (while using a 'tag' property as the html tag and than deleting it so it will not appear as an attribute).

```
for(var elem in div) {
    var temp = document.createElement(div[elem].tag);
    delete div[elem].tag;
    for(var prop in div[elem]) {
        temp.setAttribute(prop,input[prop]);
    }
    parentDiv.appendChild(temp);
}
```

The problem is I have more things I would like to add to the element that cannot be added thru attributes. Like: innerText. So maybe I could make the array an array of properties that I can merge into the 'temp' node?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could just handle that in a different section just before the for loop like this

```
for(var elem in div) {
  var temp = document.createElement(div[elem].tag);
  delete div[elem].tag;

  // add the other properties
  ["innerHtml", "innerText"].forEach(function (attr) {
     if(div[ele][attr]) {
        temp[attr] = div[ele][attr]
        delete div[ele][attr];
  });

  // add the attributes
  for(var prop in div[elem]) {
     temp.setAttribute(prop.input[prop]);
  }
  parentDiv.appendChild(temp);
}
```